# Drag And Drop ShadowBuilder

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am trying to utilize the shadow builder for android drag and drop. I noticed that it always paints in semi transparent mode. What should I do to paint something rigid in there?
I even tried something like

```
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
  canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2,paint);
```

but it is still semi-transparent.
I ran out of ideas.... help!

Answer (score 0):

You can Use setAlpha to control Transparency :

```
paint.setAlpha(255);
```

255 for fully opaque and 0 for fully transparent